# TypeError: cannot read property setState of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am receiving the data from server but not able to display it on the browser. I am receiving error as:

> caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```
import React from 'react';

import axios from 'axios';
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
    posts:'hello',
    dos:[]
    }

};


    componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.1.9:8082`)
      .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      this.setState({dos:data});
      });
  }

   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Hello World!!!
            <h1>{this.state.posts}</h1>
            <h2>{this.state.dos}</h2>
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: try this.setState({dos:[data]}) and in render try <h2>{this.state.dos[0]}</h2>

Comment: `console.log(data)` printing the data properly ??

Comment: in console.log(data) it is printing properly

Comment: @vikas i am getting same error setState not undefined

Comment: constructor is proper, no need to change that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a context issue, your mistake is that you didn't bind all the way down to the anonymous function. What you probably want to do is use arrow functions, try this:

```
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get(`http://192.168.1.9:8082`)
    .then(data => this.setState({dos:data}););
}
```

Arrow functions always keep the context of this.

Alternate solution:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://192.168.1.9:8082`)
      .then(function(data) {
         console.log(data);
         this.setState({dos:data});
      }).bind(this);
}
```

Comment: @ mayamk  it is showing error "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {data, status, statusText, headers, config, request}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons."

Comment: this is happening because you are directly rendering an object in html in this line `<h2>{this.state.dos}</h2>`, replace it by the specific property like: `<h2>{this.state.dos.data}</h2>`

Comment: you can not render whole object in html directly, you have to you the specific property, lets `a={a:1,b:2}`  to render this you have to use `<div>{a.a} , {a.b}</div>`

Comment: data that u are storing in state contains these keys `data, status, statusText, headers, config, request`.

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    axios.get(`http://192.168.1.9:8082`)
      .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      self.setState({dos:data});
      });
  }
```